# Half hexagon shape with one element

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm trying to replicate the following shape with no success:

[image]

I'm guessing I'll need some `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements along with the following css:

```
#pentagon {
    position: relative;
    width: 78px;
    height:50px;
    background:#3a93d0;
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Take a look here http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-shape-generator.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

Comment: How is that a duplicate, it's a different shape?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Using Border Method:**

You can do it using the below CSS. The shape is obtained by placing a triangle shape at the bottom of the rectangle using `:after` pseudo element. The triangular part is achieved using `border` method.

```css
.pentagon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 78px;
  background: #3a93d0;
  position: relative;
}
.pentagon:after {
  border: 39px solid #3a93d0;
  border-top-width: 15px;
  border-color: #3a93d0 transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="pentagon"></div>
```

---

**Using CSS Transforms:**

This approach uses `rotate`, `skewX` and hence would need a fully CSS3 compliant browser to work properly. The advantage of this approach is that it allows borders to be added around the shape unlike when using `border` method. The drawback is that it needs additional calculations for the angles.

It is a modified version of the short triangle method mentioned in this [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/IjKvp) by [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).

```css
.pentagon {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 78px;
  background: #3a93d0;
}
.pentagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 12px;
  left: 0;
  width: 46px;
  height: 38px;
  background: #3a93d0;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(29deg) skewX(-30deg);
}
.pentagon.bordered {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #3a93d0;
}
.pentagon.bordered:before {
  width: 44px;
  height: 37px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #3a93d0;
  border-color: transparent #3a93d0 #3a93d0 transparent;
  transform: rotate(29deg) skewX(-30deg);
}
/* Just for demo */

.pentagon {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="pentagon"></div>
<div class="pentagon bordered"></div>
```

---

**Using CSS Skew Transforms:**

This approach uses just `skew()` (along both X and Y axes) and does not need any complex angle calculations. It just needs the dimensions and position of the pseudo-element to be adjusted as the dimension of the parent changes.

```css
.pentagon {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 78px;
  border: 1px solid #3a93d0;
  border-bottom: none;
  background: aliceblue;
}
.pentagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 10px;  /* parent height - child height -1px */
  left: -1px;
  width: 39px;
  height: 39px;  /* width of parent/2 */
  border-right: 1px solid #3a93d0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3a93d0;
  background: aliceblue;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: matrix(1, 0.414213562373095, -1, 0.41421356237309515, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="pentagon">
</div>
```

The above snippet uses `matrix` transform because as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), the `skew(x, y)` is removed and should not be used anymore. The [Matrix Resolutions](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/matrix/) site can be used to obtain the equivalent matrix function. The matrix function for `rotate(45deg) skew(-22.5deg, -22.5deg)` is

```
matrix(1, 0.414213562373095, -1, 0.41421356237309515, 0, 0).
```

---

**Using Clip Path:**

Here is another approach to creating the pentagon shape with `clip-path`. Either a pure CSS `clip-path` or one with inline SVG can be used depending on required browser support. CSS `clip-path` is supported only by Webkit browsers at present.

IE (all versions) do not support either the CSS or the SVG clip-path.

```css
.pentagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  height: calc(75px / 1.414);
  background: #3a93d0;
}
.pentagon.css {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 66%, 50% 100%, 100% 66%, 100% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 66%, 50% 100%, 100% 66%, 100% 0%);
}
.pentagon.svg {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
.pentagon.bordered:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  background: white;
}
.pentagon.css.bordered:after {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 66%, 50% 100%, 100% 66%, 100% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 66%, 50% 100%, 100% 66%, 100% 0%);
}
.pentagon.svg.bordered:after {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
/* Just for demo */

.pentagon {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipper" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M0,0 0,0.66 0.5,1 1,0.66 1,0z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<h3>CSS Clip Path</h3>

<div class="pentagon css"></div>
<div class="pentagon bordered css"></div>

<h3>SVG Clip Path</h3>
<div class="pentagon svg"></div>
<div class="pentagon bordered svg"></div>
```

Comment: You don't need "additional calculations for the angles"! it can be done using `scaleX` + `rotate 45deg`

Comment: @ThePragmatick: That would still need calculation of the scale percentage like the 1.57 in your sample.

Answer (score 4):

You can try an alternate approach using transform `scaleX` and `rotate: 45deg;`. This makes it very easy to create the bottom part of the shape.

```
transform: scaleX() rotate(45deg);
```

**Working**

*sorry for bad quality gif! :(

[image]

**Sans border:**

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nsq2pqh/)**

```css
#pent{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}
#pent:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width:45px; 
    height:45px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.57) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1.57) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1.57) rotate(45deg);
    transform: scaleX(1.57) rotate(45deg);
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="pent"></div>
```

**With border :**

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9kpcgLm/)**

```css
#pent{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
#pent:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: -1px;
    width:45px; 
    height:45px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.57) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1.57) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1.57) rotate(45deg);
    transform: scaleX(1.57) rotate(45deg);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="pent"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**[See a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uxdy3ym1/)** - basically it uses [css triangles](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) and a [pseudo element](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) to give a place for the triangle.

```
.shape {
    position: relative;
    width: 78px;
    height:30px;
    background:#3a93d0;
}

.shape:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 39px 0 39px;
    border-color: #3a93d0 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#pentagon
{ 
    position: relative;
    width: 54px;
    border-width: 40px 18px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #3a93d0;
}


#pentagon:after {
    border-color: #3a93d0 transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 21px 45px 0;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: -17px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use css3 you can do it with css 
only problem is this implementation is not responsive. :(

```
<pre>

    <div class="moregrey"></div>
    <div class="arrowdown"></div>

    .moregrey
    {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 30px;
        background: #3f3f40;
    }
    .arrowdown
    {
        border-top:50px solid #3f3f40;
        border-left:500px solid transparent;
        border-bottom:500px solid transparent;
        border-right:500px solid transparent;
        display:block;
        width:0px;
        height:10px;
    }

</pre>

<pre>
 http://jsfiddle.net/jmqoj5nh/1/
</pre>
```