# Hexagon with border and image

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have the following code for a hexagon. I need a border around the hexagon and an image as a background of the hexagon instead of a plain color.

```css
body {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}
#hex1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#color1 {
  background-color: #D93;
}
.hexagon-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon {
  height: 100%;
  width: 57.735%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 21.1325%;
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.hexagon:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 21.1325%;
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="hex1" class="hexagon-wrapper">
  <span id="color1" class="hexagon"></span>
</div>
```

Here is a link with the [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVeReO)

Comment: You may find this helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418486/hexagon-shape-with-a-border-outline/31919429#31919429. It is not the same approach as the one you're using but a different method to achieve the same result.

Comment: You might find this helpful too http://css-shapes.xyz/hexagon

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest changing your approach. An [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) would be the most fexible way to achieve this. And it isn't complicated, especialy for simple shapes like hexagons.

Here is an example using the [polygon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon) element, the image fills the polygon with the [pattern element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern) and the border is added with CSS (`stroke` and `stroke-width` properties) :

```css
svg{
  width:30%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#hex{
  stroke-width:2;
  stroke: teal;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg" x="-25" width="150" height="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon id="hex" points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach not yet covered, is to use CSS `clip-path` property, which is very simlar – but not quite the same as – the SVG solution [offered by web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34263694/82548).

Here we use a clip path to shape both the outer, and inner, elements, using a `background-color` on the outer element to emulate the border and set `margin` on the inner element to control the `border-width`:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
div.hexagon-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 38%, 81% 100%, 19% 100%, 0 38%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 38%, 81% 100%, 19% 100%, 0 38%);
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.hexagon-wrapper .hexagon {
  display: block;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 38%, 81% 100%, 19% 100%, 0 38%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 38%, 81% 100%, 19% 100%, 0 38%);
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon-wrapper">
  <img class="hexagon" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/1" />
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dqaccvj4/).

References:

- [`clip-path` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).
- [`clip-path` (W3C)](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/css-masking-1/#the-clip-path).

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your CSS to add borders over it.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKaJJZ
In order to add background image:
Make the slices of the image and add it as background of each rectangle (3 rectangles you created in CSS) So that after joining 3 slices it becomes a single image

```
<div id="hex1" class="hexagon-wrapper">
    <span id="color1" class="hexagon"></span>
</div>
body { background: #ecf0f1; }
#hex1 { width: 200px; height: 200px; }
#color1 { background-color: #D93; }
.hexagon-wrapper { text-align: center; margin: 20px; position: relative; display: inline-block; }
.hexagon { height: 100%; width: 60%; display: inline-block; border-top:5px solid red; border-bottom:4px solid red; }
.hexagon:before { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 20%; background-color: inherit; height: inherit; width: inherit; content: ''; transform: rotate(60deg); border-top:5px solid red; border-bottom:5px solid red; }
.hexagon:after { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 20.1%; background-color: inherit; height: inherit; width: inherit; content: ''; transform: rotate(-60deg); border-top:5px solid red; border-bottom:5px solid red;  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is also another way to make the border because if I zoom the hexagon, the border is not perfect at edges.