# inside Image into shaped frame using css

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to keep uploaded image inside a hexagonal frame. I generated css from [this website](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) and it works fine in some browser.

Code:

```
.frame-1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 320px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 98%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 98%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

But, It don't work on some other major browser like firefox etc.

So, I tried to use a transparent background shaped image over the main image. But, I cannot make it working!

Code:

```
<div class="frame-2">
  <img src="image.jpg">
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div> 

.frame-2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
}
.mask {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/M40TJ9Z.png') no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}
```

What is the best way to make it which supports all the major browsers? Thanks in advance.

[**Fiddle Work Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/1Le90v10/1/)

Comment: Cross browser hexagons with an image fill are not easy to create with CSS. For FF support, you could use inline SVG like in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418486/hexagon-shape-with-a-border-outline/31919429#31919429

Comment: Or you could refer to this beautiful answer by web-tiki - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114920/responsive-grid-of-hexagons It is a lot more complex than using clip-path or SVG but that is your best bet for doing this cross browser with CSS.

Comment: Are there any polyfills available / have you tried any?

Comment: sorry, don't understand your question @P3t3r6 what's polyfills?

Comment: mix-blend-mode could be an hint too : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oxMbqv  (but IE still fails at this time ) where others  answers pointed by harry works

Comment: > "A polyfill, or polyfiller, is a piece of code (or plugin) that provides the technology that you, the developer, expect the browser to provide natively. Flattening the API landscape if you will." [source](https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill)
I didn't spend too much time searching, but I only found [this one](https://github.com/AlfonsoFilho/ClipPath). I haven't tested, and it is 2 years old, but still ... give it a try, might solve it

Comment: @P3t3r6, it didn't help :(
https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/1Le90v10/4/